# "Не" с причастиями

Tags: пунктуация

Слитно или раздельно пишется в данном случае причастие "необнаруженным"?

Уловленные чувствительным к необнаруженным внешним полям мозгом ассоциации сна оказываются иногда вещими, предвосхищая ситуации будущего.

Comment: Слитно, но я несколько раз прочитал фразу, прежде, чем понял, где заканчивается составной причастный оборот. Если изменить порядок слов на такой, при котором он выделится запятыми, она будет доходчивее.

Ассоциации сна, уловленные чувствительным к необнаруженным внешним полям мозгом, иногда оказываются вещими, предвосхищая ситуации будущего.

Comment: Да, предложение действительно запутано.

Comment: Его надо перестроить хотя бы так: "Ассоциации сна, уловленные чувствительным к необнаруженным внешним полям мозгом, оказываются иногда вещими, предвосхищая ситуации будущего".

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае ''не" с причастием пишется слитно. Слитно пишется не с действительными и полными страдательными причастиями, если при них нет зависимых слов: невыполненная работа, невычитанная рукопись, недвигающийся объект, непрочитанная книга — в этих случаях причастия с не можно заменить синонимичным словом без не (как и у прилагательных): Непросохшую (сырую) одежду спешно пялит на себя (Тв). В вашем случае причастие можно заменить синонимом: скрытым.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы понять смысл, воспроизведём прямой порядок:Ассоциации сна,уловленные мозгом, чувствительным к необнаруженным внешним полям, оказываются иногда вещими, предвосхищая ситуации будущего.

К необнаруженным - зависимых слов нет, можно заменить словом "тайным, скрытым", значит, одиночное отглагольное прилагательное - слитно.

Comment: Слово "уловленные" какое-то не очень...

Comment: Ну. если дан такой текст, с ним и работаем